# Encouraging users to document new tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Often when users, mostly new *(those who get association bonuses)* ask a question, to identify it or its basis they will often create new tags and leave them as just that.

For others of us who have no idea what this is, might want to help or are just interested it should be there. This also creates a plethora of [cryptic tags that are either localized, vague or useless.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new)

**I propose implementing a way of encouraging people to document any *new* tags they create.**

**How can we prod users to document tags or encourage them to use related ones or at least limit the number of additional tags on a question?**

*Eg.* I saw [donyatsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donyatsu) this morning and was intrigued but it wasn't until after several google searches I was finally able to put a synopsis to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remember that this, first and foremost, is a Q&A site.

People come here to ask questions, not build a community. They don't mind if the tag is documented or not.

If they care, great, we'll welcome the help. But I don't want to force, or even hint to people that they can document their tags. There are more useful activities on the site that they can take place in (Like asking, answering, flagging, suggesting edits).

We want to have the involved in the community first, if they want to join. When they do, we can introduce tag editing to them.

In short, I, a visitor from Google came here to ask a question. Not to document tags or help this community, I want my question answered, this site's job is to provide with the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, keep in mind that a visitor from google wouldn't be able to create tags (*new user*). :) I'm talking about the ones who 'settle' down, join from other se sites etc.. I might have weighed on the new user a bit too much but what I could have said or rather meant was as you said In your second to last paragraph, once they have become involved enough don't just create the tags and leave them empty.

Comment: I, a visitor from Google, might happen to have a 40K account on [so]. Users who are active on other sites usually are aware of the ability to edit tag wiki and excerpts. I see where you're coming from, but it's not something we can ask a user to do, it needs to come from himself :)